# build dynamic android layouts

Tags: java, android, layout, dynamic

am trying to build android app with a dynamic layout to support multiple screens

am thinking about build all my app for a certain device with a fixed dimensions like Motorola Droid , say that the button will be 50 width 50 height

and after i finished all the app , i will reedit the sizes of elements to be a ratio betweetn the right  place of them and the  dimensions of the new device

also Drawables will be Scalable Drawables and i will use only the Drawables folder and remove others :
 - drawable-hdpi
 - drawable-ldpi
 - drawable-mdpi

so i will have only one Drawables folder and only one layout xml file for every activity

and most of my layouts will be hard coded using java

so the question is : is it a  true method for development   ?!

may be you will ask , why ?

so my answer is , as i think my method is easer than using :

- res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
- res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
- res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
- res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
- res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
- res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
- res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
- res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and probably the best) way to create layouts that support all screen sizes is to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Comment: u r right , but if my app have lots of details , think about deferent sizes and screens .

Comment: I get the concern. Another good implementation, assuming your layout is not in a gallery/horizontalScrollView/ or some other scrolling-required View, is to place everything within a `LinearLayout`, and place that `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`.

Comment: so here i will :  have only one Drawables folder and only one layout xml file for every activity ?!

Comment: Exactly. The simpler the better.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can manage resoution variation of different devices by keeping the images in  drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-ldpi folder.
then screen sizes by providing different layout for different screen size categories by specifying layout-small,layout-large,layout-xlarge.
also you can increase number of devices supported by using nine patch and relative layout [check this google official documentation regarding this topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

hope this help.

thanks.

Comment: the point here , that i need to write only one layout file and use only one image for every button